# Создать представление из двух таблиц если в связанной таблице несколько записей для каждой записи из главной таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы: Customer и CustomerAddress. Таблицы связаны через CustomerId

Таблица Customer

```
CustomerId | Name
    1        Вова
    2        Петя
```

Таблица CustomerAddress:

```
Id |CustomerId | IsResidenceAddress | IsNominalAddress | Address
 1      1              Y                  N              Ул Пухова 2/12
 2      1              N                  Y              Ул Антонова 4/17
 3      2              Y                  N              Ул Степанова 28/3
 4      2              N                  Y              Ул Жукова 3/21
```

Нужно получить представление, в котором для каждого пользователя будет по одной записи, в
которой будут указаны все данные из 2-х таблиц (оба адреса)
Пример:

```
CustomerId | Name | ResidenceAddress    | NominalAddress
     1        Вова     Ул Пухова 2/12     ул Антонова 4/17
     2        Петя     Ул Степанова 28/3  Ул Жукова 3/21
```

Как написать запрос для такого представления?
Хелп ми плиз камрады!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.Customerid,
       c.name,
       (SELECT ca.address
          FROM CustomerAddress ca
         WHERE ca.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
                AND UPPER (ca.IsResidenceAddress) = 'Y')
          ResidenceAddress,
       (SELECT ca.address
          FROM CustomerAddress ca
         WHERE ca.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
               AND UPPER (ca.IsNominalAddress) = 'Y')
          NominalAddress
  FROM Customer c;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Такое решение конечно применимо (я его сейчас и использую), но я думал может есть какое-то менее затратное решение. Потому что, на самом деле у меня в обоих таблица несколько сотен тысяч записей и получается достаточно "дорогой" запрос в итоге